# iOS UITableView doesn't reload data when searching

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am implementing a search page like Instagram's - such that when you go to the search tab, you see trending searches (with dynamic sections) etc but when you start typing in the search box, the trending searches go away and the search results are shown.

I did just that but it doesn't seem to work. 
A) No results are shown when I search for something (I log the response from the api calls - I am getting the data correctly for sure).
B) I don't go back to show trending results even after I hit cancel (Again, I print in the cancelSearch action, the function is being called for sure)

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class SearchVC: UITableViewController {

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

var sections = [String]()
var allTrendingOfferings = [[OfferingModel]]()
var allSearchResultOfferings = [OfferingModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sections = // data from backend
    allTrendingOfferings = // data from backend

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if (searchController.isActive) {
        return ""
    }
    return self.sections[section]
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if (searchController.isActive) {
        return 1
    }
    return self.sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (searchController.isActive) {
        return allSearchResultOfferings.count
    }
    return allTrendingOfferings[section].count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "offeringCell", for: indexPath) as! SeachTVCell

    if (searchController.isActive) {
        let offering = allSearchResultOfferings[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        let offering = allTrendingOfferings[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }
    // configure cell and
    return cell
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    allSearchResultOfferings = // data fetched from backend
    self.tableView.reloadData() // done asynchronously (after receiving data)
}

func searchCancel() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

}

extension SearchVC: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController){
        if !searchController.isActive {
            searchCancel()
        }
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText:searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code inside `filterContentForSearchText`. The most likely cause is that `reloadData` is being called before `allSearchResultOfferings` is updated due to the asynchronous nature of the call.

Comment: You should call `reloadData()` in main thread. `DispatchQueue.main.async { tableView. reloadData() }`

Comment: @NandiinBao Yep, I am calling reloadData() in mainthread once I get a response back from the api call!

Comment: @Michael Thanks guys! I fixed it... I just had to quit xcode, clean and rebuild the project... Spent like 5 hours on this!

Answer (score 0):

False alarm - Had to quit Xcode, clean and rebuild the project. It works like a charm now.